# C# Converting UTC to local time in a function dataset

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, dataset

I need a help to change the form of my method populates my database.

I use an API to communicate with an industrial equipment through the OPC protocol.

This API takes as parameter a universal time zone (UTC), but I have a difference of +3 hours in the grating (UTC) universal.

within my dataset I use this API for a class that returns me three properties: data value, quality and timestamp

I need to convert to local time in time to save this property Timestamp in my database.

follows a class example of how my class.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using OpcLabs.EasyOpc.DataAccess;

namespace LogAsStringToSql
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            const string connectionString =
                "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=QuickOPCExamples;Integrated Security=true";

            Console.WriteLine("Starting up...");
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                // Create all necessary ADO.NET objects.
                var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM SimpleLog", connection);
                var dataSet = new DataSet();
                adapter.FillSchema(dataSet, SchemaType.Source, "SimpleLog");
                adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter).GetInsertCommand();
                DataTable table = dataSet.Tables["SimpleLog"];

                Console.WriteLine("Logging for 30 seconds...");
                // Subscribe to an OPC item, using an anonymous method to process the notifications.
                int[] handles = EasyDAClient.DefaultInstance.SubscribeMultipleItems(
                    new[]
                        {
                            new DAItemGroupArguments("", "OPCLabs.KitServer.2", "Simulation.Incrementing (1 s)", 100, null),
                            new DAItemGroupArguments("", "OPCLabs.KitServer.2", "Simulation.Ramp (10 s)", 1000, null),
                            new DAItemGroupArguments("", "OPCLabs.KitServer.2", "Simulation.Register_BSTR", 1000, null),
                            new DAItemGroupArguments("", "OPCLabs.KitServer.2", "Simulation.Register_BOOL", 1000, null)
                        },
                    (_, eventArgs) =>
                    {
                        Console.Write(".");
                        // In this example, we only log valid data. Production logger would also log errors.
                        if (eventArgs.Vtq != null)
                        {
                            // Fill a DataRow with the OPC data, and add it to a DataTable.
                            table.Rows.Clear();
                            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                            row["ItemID"] = eventArgs.ItemDescriptor.ItemId;
                            row["Value"] = eventArgs.Vtq.Value; // The DataRow will make the conversion to a string.
                            row["Timestamp"] = (eventArgs.Vtq.Timestamp < (DateTime)SqlDateTime.MinValue)
                                                   ? (DateTime)SqlDateTime.MinValue
                                                   : eventArgs.Vtq.Timestamp;
                            row["Quality"] = (short)eventArgs.Vtq.Quality;
                            table.Rows.Add(row);

                            // Update the underlying DataSet using an insert command.
                            adapter.Update(dataSet, "SimpleLog");
                        }
                    }
                    );
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60 * 1000);
                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Shutting down...");
                EasyDAClient.DefaultInstance.UnsubscribeMultipleItems(handles);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Finished.");
        }
    }
}
```

How could I be changing my current method to use ToLocalTime () method on the DateTime to receive the timestamp in localtime?

```
row["Timestamp"] = (eventArgs.Vtq.Timestamp < (DateTime)SqlDateTime.MinValue)
                                                   ? (DateTime)SqlDateTime.MinValue
                                                   : eventArgs.Vtq.Timestamp;
```

I'm having trouble understanding how to change this, any help will be very welcome thanks.

Comment: Convert `eventArgs.Vtq.Timestamp` to a DateTime.

Comment: Ramhound was trying to do this, but I could not change my method this way Andriy Buday showed a very simple way that I tested here and worked, but anyway thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it just like below?

```
row["Timestamp"] = (eventArgs.Vtq.Timestamp < (DateTime)SqlDateTime.MinValue)
                                                   ? (DateTime)SqlDateTime.MinValue
                                                   : eventArgs.Vtq.Timestamp.ToLocalTime();
```

Code above only ensures that you are not trying to save too old date into database, which would throw an exception. If it is not the case you can save your date converted to your local time. See [?: operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Could be that I misunderstood your issue.

Comment: Exactly, was so simple that I was not able to see it, was trying to do otherwise and changing variables using the method completely.

Thank Andriy Buday you saved my day;)